# How not to use redundant fors when it comes to querying multiple tables

Tags: django, for-loop, view, models

So I have this kind of urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<loc>\w+)/(?P<ctg>\w+)/$', 'beta.views.queryCtgFromIndex'),
```

which as it can be seen, when accessing, for example, /loc/ctgx/ the queryCtgFromIndex is called and it calculates something based on ctgx table

i actually have 5 tables which can be queried, so the valid urls can be:

```
/loc/ctg1/, /loc/ctg2/, ..., /loc/ctg5/
```

in my view i am doing something like:

```
if ctg == ctg1: do something, ctg1.objects.all() etc...
if ctg == ctg2: do something, ctg2.objects.all() etc...
...
if ctg == ctg5: do something, ctg5.objects.all() etc...
```

The *do something* code is quite big and my question would be: Can I rewrite my code in some fashion to get rid of the five fors and have clean code? ...something like in bash would be, fictional example: $ctg.objects.all() ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework let you interact with models in a generic way, something like

```
my_model = contenttypes.objects.get(model='my model name')
my_model.model_class().objects.filter(...whatever you would normally do)
```

you'd probably want to use a whitelist to make sure only the user can't interact with e.g. your user model in this way, e.g.

```
if model_name not in ['list', 'of', 'allowed', 'models']:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()  #or 404
```

Comment: great! thanks, you saved me a lot of trouble and lines of code :)

i did - if 'model_name' in str(my_model.model_class()): do sumthin
else: 403/404